# Json single object string into List<string>

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am having a hard time getting a simple json object into a List

```
var returnedJson = ["applicant", "recruiter", "team"];
```

NOT WORKING

```
List<string> list = (List<string>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(returnedJson);
```

How can I parse the json string into a List?

Comment: In future, rather than just "not working" can you say what you observe vs what you expected? Is it a compile-time error, an exception, something else? Please edit your post to make it clearer for future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify `List<string>` as the type argument to `DeserializeObject`:

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(returnedJson);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//DeserializeObject<T>() needs type T. 
//Thus you've to specify result type in place of T no an explicit cast is required.
List<string> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(returnedJson );
```